# Conflicto con librerías Flexslider y PhotoSwipe en woocommerce

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

Cordial saludo a todos.

Estoy tratando de modificar el flex-viewport de la pagina single-product de woocommerce en wordpress con el fin de hacer un slider que me permita mostrar las demás imágenes del producto haciendo clic sobre las flechas de navegación laterales.

Esta página muestra el producto usando las librerías FlexSlider para animaciones de transición y estructurar las vista "pero ha sido modificada por woocommerce para no crear las flechas de navegación para controlar el slider , solo puede hacerse desde las miniaturas inferiores" y PhotoSwipe que da otras funcionalidades como Zoom al mover el mouse sobre la imagen y demás.

Si desactivo la librería PhotoSwipe me funciona correctamente, pero al volver a activarla, cuando hago clic sobre alguna de las flechas de navegación, me reconoce ese mismo clic 4 o 5 veces en la dirección clicada y me traslada a la imagen ubicada en la posición 4 o 5.

Las modificaciones las estoy realizando sobre la librería jquery.flexslider.js

El código que realicé dentro de la librería jquery.flexslider.js es el siguiente

```
//ARROWNAVIGATION
        if(slider.vars.arrownavigation){
          let cbtnleft = "btn-display-left"; /*clase boton izquierdo*/
          let cbtnright = "btn-display-right"; /*clase boton derecho*/
          let anleft = '<button class="btn '+cbtnleft+'">&#10094;</button>'; /*etiqueta de boton izquierdo*/
          let anright = '<button class="btn '+cbtnright+'">&#10095;</button>'; /*etiqueta de boton derecho*/
          let zona = '.flex-viewport'; /*Zona de accion*/
          let zonaI = '.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper'; /*Zona Interna*/
          slider.areaNavScaffold = $('<div class="arrownavigation"></div>')
          slider.arrownavigationScaffold = $(anleft+anright); /*Construir los botones en el DOM*/

          $(zona).mouseenter(function(){
            
            $(zona).append(slider.areaNavScaffold);
            $('.arrownavigation').append(slider.arrownavigationScaffold);

            $('.'+cbtnleft).mouseup(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              (slider.currentSlide == 0)?slider.flexAnimate(slider.currentSlide,slider.vars.pauseOnAction):slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('prev'), slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
              console.log("izq-> "+slider.currentSlide);
            });
            $('.'+cbtnright).mouseup(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              (slider.currentSlide == slider.last)?slider.flexAnimate(slider.currentSlide,slider.vars.pauseOnAction):slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget('next'), slider.vars.pauseOnAction);
              
              console.log("der-> "+slider.currentSlide);
            });
          })
          $(zona).mouseleave(function(){
            $('.arrownavigation').remove();
            $('.btn').remove();
          })
          
        }
```

En este código he agregado las flechas de navegación dentro de un div que también agregué dentro del flex-viewport

He probado agregando las flechas de navegación directamente dentro del flex-viewport pero obtengo el mismo resultado, sigue reconociéndome 4 o 5 clics al habilitar la librería PhotoSwipe.

Poner limitaciones de tiempo entre las transiciones de imágenes y obtengo el mismo resultado.